# Find an equation for the conic that satisfies the given conditions.

Tags: calculus

Find an equation for the conic that satisfies the given conditions.

parabola,    focus $(−10, 0)$,     directrix $x = 4$

I know how to do this type of problems and found the equation $y^2=-28(x+1)$ but this answer is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if we have
$$(y-n)^2=4p(x-m),$$
then the vertex is $(m,n)$, the axis of symmetry is $y=m$, the focus is $(p+m,n)$, the directrix is $x=m-p$.

Hence, for your case, you'll have
$$p+m=-10,\ n=0,\ m-p=4\Rightarrow n=0, m=-3, p=-7.$$
So, the answer will be $y^2=-28(x+3)$, which is not $y^2=-28(x+1)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still getting y^2=−28(x+1) which I think is correct but when I submit the equation it's marked as incorrect...

Comment: @Mio: I added a bit. Take a look.